# How to render threaded comment with Vue.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have an array of comments like these:

```
[
 { id: 1, in_response_to: null, content: 'abc' },
 { id: 2, in_response_to: 1, content: 'def' },
 { id: 3, in_response_to: 1, content: 'ghi' },
 { id: 4, in_response_to: null, content: 'jkl' },
 { id: 5, in_response_to: 2, content: 'mno' },
]
```

How would I render threaded comment like structure with these data like:

```
+ abc
    + def
        + mno
    + ghi
+ jkl
```

With `<ul>` and `<li>` maybe.

I don't know where to start with these with Vue js. I can render one or two level with component, `v-for` and `v-if` but I don't know how many level I'd have in data. Do I have to set a limit on how many level it can render at a time or does Vue have some way to render threaded comments of arbitrary level ?

Comment: https://jacobmartella.com/2017/08/01/displaying-threaded-comments-vuejs/

Comment: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-edge-cases.html#Recursive-Components

Comment: you'll want to change your data structure to a nested data structure (tree) then use the recursive component rendering @RobertHarvey referenced above.